# Type error cannot concatenate 'str' and 'ErrorList' objects

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

my code

```
def is_valid(self):
    form = super(UserCreateForm, self).is_valid()
    for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
        if f != '__all_':
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})
    return form
```

traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/saurabh/Desktop/project/ribbit/ribbit_app/views.py" in signup
  48.         if user_form.is_valid():

File "/home/saurabh/Desktop/project/ribbit/ribbit_app/forms.py" in is_valid
  18.                 self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  203.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/html.py" in strip_tags
  134.         s.feed(value)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py" in feed
  113.         self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data

Exception Type: TypeError at /signup

Exception Value: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'ErrorList' objects
```

Comment: What's the context of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django [form.errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) is a dictionary, the keys are the field names, and the values are `lists` of Unicode strings representing the error messages. The error messages are stored in `lists` because a field can have multiple error messages:

```
>>> f.errors
{'sender': ['Enter a valid email address.'], 'subject': ['This field is required.']}
```

And [strip_tags(value)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.strip_tags) get value as  `string`  but you pass to it an `list` object:

```
def is_valid(self):
    form = super(UserCreateForm, self).is_valid()
    for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
        # Here `error` is a list of errors for `f` field. (may be one or more)
        if f != '__all_':
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})
    return form
```

So you need to change this line:

```
self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})
```

To: (for get just first error)

```
self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error[0])})
```

Or to: (for have all errors)

```
self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(", ".join(error))})
```